# like sql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table with a date datatype (eg 2013-03-08), now I have a dropdown box that only have a year in it. I made query using the $this->db-like() syntax to fetch the record with that year, but I'm getting this error.

```
Error Number:

ERROR: operator does not exist: date ~~ text LINE 3: WHERE "hire_date" LIKE '%STR!!_TO!!_DATE(, ''!!%Y'... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

SELECT * FROM "profile"."record" WHERE "hire_date" LIKE '%STR!!_TO!!_DATE(, ''!!%Y'')%' ESCAPE '!'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\profiling\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

this is my code in model

```
$where = $this->input->post('s_year');

$this->db->like('hire_date', "STR_TO_DATE($where, '%Y')", FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('profiling.record');

return $query->result;
```

Comment: You can't put a function call in `like()`, just a pattern

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like

```
$where = $this->input->post('s_year');    
$this->db->where('YEAR(hire_date)',$where , FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('profiling.record');
```

Or if the type of your date column is string you can do so

```
$where = $this->input->post('s_year');    
$this->db->where("YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(hire_date,'%Y-%m-%d'))",$where , FALSE);
$query = $this->db->get('profiling.record');
```

Note `STR_TO_DATE` is used to convert sting to date but the format you provide in second parameter of `STR_TO_DATE` must match with the current format of string date so you can't use `STR_TO_DATE($where, '%Y')`

If you have date type for the column `hire_date` this should work

```
$this->db->where("YEAR(hire_date) ='". $where ."' ",null, FALSE);
```

From the error i guess you are using postgre database driver for postgre you can use `EXTRACT`

```
$this->db->where("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date) ='". $where ."' ",null, FALSE);
```

Comment: I'm using the like function because the whole date (2013-03-30) is recorded in the database which have a date type not varchar (I can't change this one cause this is already being used live on another web app) and i'm querying the hired personnel during a certain year. and also not working it still produce and error number.

Comment: @user3457998 see my updated answer ans also if there is error you should also post the exact details for the error

Comment: Using the updated code you provided it produced. Error Number:

ERROR: function year(date) does not exist LINE 3: WHERE YEAR(hire_date) ='' ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

SELECT * FROM "profiling.record" WHERE YEAR(hire_date) =''

Comment: @user3457998 the above error is from postgre database if thats the case see my updated answer and one thing i would say when you ask a question on stackoverflow please include necessary details with proper tags